# Cannot modify association because the source reflection class is associated via :has_many

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-2

My associations in a Rails 2 project are as follows:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :attrs, :through => :user, :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :order => 'id DESC', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :attr, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Attr < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :roles, :through => :user
end
```

I am upgrading my project to rails 3. And while trying to delete user in rails 3, I get the following error:

Cannot modify association 'Role#attrs' because the source reflection class 'Attr' is associated to 'User' via :has_many.

But for the same thing, in rails 2 the users get deleted fine. I have never worked on rails 2 so I had to ask here.

What Can I do to fix this? I checked other answers but they don't seem to apply to my case.

Answer (score 0):

In User Model
has_many :attr, :dependent => :destroy

It should be
has_many :attrs, :dependent => :destroy